# Nested algorithm or items

Tags: lists

Am trying for something like this:

```
  Step1 : Some Text
  Step2 : Some Text
```

After few lines I want something like this: In step1 you have to follow few more steps:

```
      Step 1.a : Some Text
      Step 1.b : Some Text
   Step 2 : Some Text
```

Can some one help me how to write this in latex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you some ideas:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{steps}
 {\begin{enumerate}[label=Step \arabic*:,leftmargin=*,align=left]}
 {\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{substeps}
 {\begin{enumerate}[label=Step \arabic{enumi}.\alph*:,leftmargin=*,align=left]}
 {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{steps}
\item Some text
  \begin{substeps}
  \item Some text
  \item Some text
  \end{substeps}
\item Some text
\end{steps}

\end{document}
```

[image]